# Arrays issue - How to add to with loops, and compare

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working my way through a practice problem to prepare for an upcoming exam, and I'm a bit stumped on what to do next.

The directions to this problem are as follows :

Ask how many users will be playing (1-n)

- Error checking and valid range checking
- Choose a random number for each player
- Ask each player (one guess per round) to enter their guess
- Error Checking
- Alert the user with “Too High”, “Too Low”, “CORRECT!”
- Record the answer for each user, if incorrect.
- If the user was correct, skip them in subsequent rounds.
- Once all players have guessed their correct number, print out the number of guesses it took for each one to guess correctly, the wrong responses, and show a ranking of the players.
- Ask if the user wishes to play again.  If so, reset all values.

The previous problem was almost identical except for the fact that it was only one person guessing.  I had no issues with that, however, arrays were not involved.  I tried editing my code from the first assignment, which worked flawlessly, and after about an hour of trying to do it without arrays I came to the conclusion that it would be unfeasible.

So far I have the following working:

I have setup an array with the number of players after asking the user, with error checking.

I have the Too High, Too low, and Correct working.

I have it asking the user if they wish to play again.

My current code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class q4_try3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int tries = 0;
        int numOfPlayers;
        boolean playerWin = false;
        boolean gameWin = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many people are playing?");
            numOfPlayers = input.nextInt();
            if(numOfPlayers<1) {
                System.out.println("There must be at least one player! Please enter a new number of players.");
                numOfPlayers = input.nextInt();
            }
        int[] players; // array with players 1 through x.  Keeps track of whose turn it is.
        players = new int[numOfPlayers];

        int[] numToGuess;
        numToGuess = new int[numOfPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i<numOfPlayers; i++) {
            numToGuess[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }



    }
}
```

Also, here is the code that I will be using for returning too high, too low, and correct.  As well as tries.

```
        while (win == false) {

                if (guess == numberToGuess) {
                    win = true;
                    numberOfWinners++;

                }
                else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
                }
                else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
                }
        }

        System.out.println("You win!");
        System.out.println("the number was" + numberToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + "tries");
```

If someone can help me understand how I can setup a loop to add to an array, and then compare an array to an `ArrayList`, because I assume we would just add the guesses into an `ArrayList` and then substract the `array.length` by the number of players to get each of their guesses, it would be a tremendous help.

Comment: When you use the word *arraylist* do you actually mean an `ArrayList`? I'm a little confused with what you are asking. Could you maybe split your questions so that we may be able to answer one by one?

Comment: This is a too broad question since it is asking too much questions in a single one. Please learn how to do a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it, be more clear and specific in your question (1 question not 9 as you have here), as is, your question is really long and poorly explained, so please edit it for a better comprehension :)

Comment: Sorry I'll try to clarify.  So I know that I need an array to hold only the players, I know this can't be an ArrayList because the order matters.  I know I also need an array for the random numbers, because again, order matters.  However, rather than make a multidimensional array to hold all of the guesses by each individual player, I know it would work much smoother if I just made an ArrayList that would hold all of their guesses.  This way, I can setup a boolean that says something like "If player X has won, subtract number of players from the ArrayList and add that number to the ArrayList

Comment: do you know how to use object oriented programming? it would make sense to make a `player` object class.